# Не обновляется срез структур

Tags: сортировка, golang

Пытаюсь добавить элементы в массив `ObjectList`, отсортировать и затем вывести на экран, но ничего не работает, элементы попросту не добавляются.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type Object struct {
    Kind    int
    Message string
}

type ObjectList []*Object

func (objl ObjectList) Add(kind int, msg string) {
    objl = append(objl, &Object{kind, msg})
}

func (objl ObjectList) Sort() {
    sort.SliceStable(objl, func(i, j int) bool {
        return objl[i].Kind < objl[j].Kind // sort from warn to fatal
    })
}

func main() {
    var list ObjectList
    list.Add(0, "WARN USE IDENT")
    list.Add(0, "WARN USE STRUCT INSTEAD")
    list.Add(1, "unexpected syntax error")
    list.Add(2, "panic")
    list.Sort()

    for _, obj := range list {
        fmt.Println(obj.Message)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши методы принимают копию среза вместо указателя на сам срез, поэтому
изменения не сохраняются.  Вот рабочий код:

```golang
func (objl *ObjectList) Add(kind int, msg string) {
    if objl == nil {
        return
    }

    *objl = append(*objl, &Object{kind, msg})
}

func (objl *ObjectList) Sort() {
    if objl == nil {
        return
    }

    sort.SliceStable(*objl, func(i, j int) bool {
        return (*objl)[i].Kind < (*objl)[j].Kind
    })
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, на самом деле сделал тоже самое до вашего ответа, удивился почему не работает и ничего не выводится, оказывается что запускал файл с тем же именем только в другой директории и с другим содержимым :)